# Order All Pages table in administration

Tags: admin

In administration, in the "All Pages" section, each time I add a new page the table is refreshed order by page Title. 
I reorder the table clicking on "Date" column to keep working on the last updated pages, but every refresh the order change again to Title.

I cannot find any plugin or way for Wordpress to remember the last order selected. Is there any way to achive this?

TL;DR I want Wordpress to remember the order of "All Pages" in the administration.

Comment: Check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plugin for that. But you can achieve this by using filters. Add following code to you theme's `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Order Admin Page List by Date by Default
 */

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_set_page_order_in_admin' );
function my_set_page_order_in_admin( $wp_query ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && $_GET['post_type'] == 'page' && 'edit.php' == $pagenow && !isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $wp_query->set( 'order', 'desc' );
    }
}
```